# Django OneToMany relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model for Images and a model for Image Categories. Each Image should relate to exactly one category, so a `ForeignKeyField` wouldn't work. I tried using a `OneToOneField`, but then I could only create one Image in each Category. What is the correct model to use for this situation?

Comment: A `ForeignKey` from `Image` to `ImageCategory` seems like the right way to go. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you think a ForeignKey wouldn't work.  On the contrary, that is exactly how to define a one-to-many relationship: in your case, from Image to Category.